# Error using a color box with xelatex

Tags: xetex, font-encodings

I have used this colorbox in a Document:

```
\newtcolorbox{Titolo}[2][]{
enhanced before skip=2mm,after skip=2mm,
colback=black!5,colframe=black!50,boxrule=0.2mm,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm,yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
varwidth boxed title*=-3cm,
boxed title style={frame code={
        \path[fill=tcbcol@back!30!black]
        ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
        arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
        ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
        arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
        \path[left color=tcbcol@back!60!black,right color=tcbcol@back!60!black,
        middle color=tcbcol@back!80!black]
        ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
        [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)
        -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
        -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
        [sharp corners]-- cycle;
    },interior engine=empty,
},
fonttitle=\bfseries,
title={#2},#1
}
```

When I compile with pdflatex I don’t have any problem, but I want to use xelatex, and I get a lot of errors, all similar to the following:

```
! \textfont 0 is undefined (character c).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $

l.115 \begin{Titolo}[colbacktitle=black]{Intro}
```

This is a sample file:

```
%Class
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{afterpage}
%Colori
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
%Commenti
\usepackage{verbatim}
%Lingua
\usepackage[english, italian]{babel}
\addto{\captionsitalian}{
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{}}
%Margini e Interlinea
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, headheight=15pt]{geometry}
%Stile di pagina principale e numeri di pagina
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%Font
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
%Matematica
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amscd, amsthm, amsfonts, amsopn}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac, faktor} 
%Tabelle
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{array}
%Liste
\usepackage{enumitem}
%Titoli
\usepackage{titles}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
%Immagini
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt}}
%Diagrammi
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%Indice
\usepackage{imakeidx}
%Collegamenti ipertestuali
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup
 {colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!75!black},
    citecolor={ForestGreen},
    urlcolor={Cerulean}}
%Controllo
\usepackage{lipsum}
%Pagine bianche
\newcommand{\Bianco}{\clearpage{{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}}

%Riquadro1
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{Frame}{
linecolor=white,
outerlinewidth=1pt,
roundcorner=20pt,
innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip,
innerbottommargin=0.5\baselineskip,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
backgroundcolor=yellow!40!white}
\mdfdefinestyle{Intro}{
linecolor=white,
outerlinewidth=1pt,
roundcorner=20pt,
innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip,
innerbottommargin=0.5\baselineskip,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
backgroundcolor=green!20!white}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{Titolo}[2][]{
enhanced,
before skip=2mm,after skip=2mm,
colback=black!5,colframe=black!50,boxrule=0.2mm,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm,yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
varwidth boxed title*=-3cm,
boxed title style={frame code={
        \path[fill=tcbcol@back!30!black]
        ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
        arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
        ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
        arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
        \path[left color=tcbcol@back!60!black,right color=tcbcol@back!60!black,
        middle color=tcbcol@back!80!black]
        ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
        [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)
        -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
        -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
        [sharp corners]-- cycle;
    },interior engine=empty,
},
fonttitle=\bfseries,
title={#2},#1
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{Titolo}[colbacktitle=black]{Intro}
Sample
\end{Titolo}
\end{document}
```

How can I solve this issue?

The complete .log file is the following:

```
--RUN xelatex (1)
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015)       (preloaded format=xelatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Prova.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk11.clo))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/appendix/appendix.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/afterpage.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/xebabel.def)))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-italian/italian.ldf))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/changepage/changepage.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-xetex.def))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3unicode-data.def)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-patches.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmss.fd)))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amscd.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xfrac/xfrac.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/faktor/faktor.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/shorttoc/shorttoc.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/titles.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/moredefs.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/slemph.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/slemph.cfg))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/titles.cfg))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titletoc.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfig/subfig.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.te
x)) (/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x)) (/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.def
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
))))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.t
ex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.t
ex)) (/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometr
ic.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code
.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.
code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.t
ex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.
tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.t
ex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarit
hmetics.code.tex)))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.c
ode.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.
tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.co
de.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations
.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)

(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.te
x)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.
code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
 (/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex

(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.t
ex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.co
de.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.t
ex)))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
 (/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.
sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.
sty)) (/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.
code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)

(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
librarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-fct/tkz-fct.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-base.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
librarycalc.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
libraryarrows.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.code.t
ex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
libraryplotmarks.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplotmarks.cod
e.tex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
librarypositioning.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
libraryshapes.misc.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes
.misc.code.tex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
librarydecorations.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecorations.code
.tex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
librarydecorations.markings.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibraryd
ecorations.markings.code.tex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
librarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibraryd
ecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
librarypatterns.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibrarypatterns.code
.tex)) (/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/numprint/numprint.sty
No configuration file `numprint.cfg' found.)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-tools-utilities.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-tools-arith.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-tools-base.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-tools-misc.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-tools-math.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-obj-points.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-obj-segments.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-base/tkz-obj-marks.tex)))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscore.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgfplotssysgeneric.code.
tex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgfplotslibrary.code.te
x)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpg
fsupp_loader.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)
Package pgfplots: loading complementary arithmetics for your pgf version...

(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpg
fsupp_pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpg
fsupp_pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpg
fsupp_trig_format.code.tex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotslistst
ructure.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotslistst
ructureext.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsarray.
code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsmatrix
.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstableshared
.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsdeque.
code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.code.tex

(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.data.cod
e.tex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.verb.code.
tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgflibrarypgfplots.surf
shading.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfs
hading.pgfsys-xetex.def
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfs
hading.pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def))))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolormap.code.t
ex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolor.code.tex)
)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsstackedplots.code.te
x)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsplothandlers.code.te
x
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code
.tex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.scaling.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscoordprocessing.code
.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.errorbars.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.markers.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsticks.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.paths.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
librarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibraryd
ecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex))))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.fil
lbetween.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfcontrib/tikzlibraryfillbe
tween.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
libraryintersections.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryintersections
.code.tex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfcontrib/tikzlibrarydecora
tions.softclip.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfcontrib/pgflibraryfillbet
ween.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpg
fsupp_pgflibraryintersections.code.tex))
Package pgfplots: loading complementary 'name path' implementation for your pgf
 version...
)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.dec
orations.softclip.code.tex))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tikz-cd/tikzlibrarycd.code.tex
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
librarymatrix.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
libraryquotes.code.tex)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.c
ode.tex))) (/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/imakeidx/imakeidx.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xpatch/xpatch.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.

(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/mdframed.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspage.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-base.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/needspace/needspace.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/md-frame-1.mdf))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbskins.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskins.code.tex' version '3.60'
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex' version '3.60'
))) (./Prova.aux) (/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} into 
your preamble.
 on input line 114.

(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./Prova.out) (./Prova.out)

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd)
(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmtt.fd)
! \textfont 0 is undefined (character f).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $

l.115 \begin{Titolo}[colbacktitle=black]{Intro}

! \textfont 0 is undefined (character i).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $

l.115 \begin{Titolo}[colbacktitle=black]{Intro}

! \textfont 0 is undefined (character l).
\Url@FormatString ...\Url@String \UrlRight \m@th $

l.115 \begin{Titolo}[colbacktitle=black]{Intro}

...

(That makes 100 errors; please try again.)
No pages of output.
Transcript written on Prova.log.
Compilation Aborted: xelatex (1) failed with status: 1
xelatex  -interaction nonstopmode  "Prova.tex" 2>&1
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Works for me (up-to-date TL2018). Could you please post the output of your log file?

Comment: TeX Live 2015 is quite old. Probably a bug has been fixed since then but I cannot test it. Have you considered updating?

Comment: I can reproduce the error with TeX Live 2014 (you're using TL 2015, but probably with an outdated version of `tcolorbox`, I have 3.90, you seem to have 3.60). I don't think there is a reasonable workaround other than updating the TeX distribution.